# Viewpager overflows the screen inside coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to use the **design support library** to implement **tabs**. The issue is that the viewpager overlaps the toolbar and tablayout when i remove the attribute

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

of the viewpager.

[viewpager overlaps the toolbar and tablayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnQtl.png)

and when i add the attribute the viewpager overflows the screen.

[viewpager overflows the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDbQL.png)

**I just need the viewpager to occupy the space left after the tablayout and the toolbar and not overflow the screen...**

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my fragment_1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tV_item1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tab1_q_persons"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0 people"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iV_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iV_minus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:text="@string/next" />

 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Any help will be appreciated*

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems late. But I send my answer.

In activity_main.xml use RelativeLayout instead of CoordinatorLayout and you can remove AppBar. For defining Toolbar as AppBar you can use this code in MainActivity.java:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

In fragment_1.xml use another widget like CardView or ScrollView instead of LinearLayout or you may use LinearLayout inside of replaced widget.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" 
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
     android:layout_below="@id/tablayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_1.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tV_item1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tab1_q_persons"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0 people"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:text="@string/next" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This solution solved same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the AppBar Layout, remove it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

This code works fine for me.

Comment: i think i need the Appbar layout otherwise the **Toolbar and Tablayout ovwelaps**.

Comment: Add android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" to your TabLayout

Comment: can you tell me what is the actual use of adding the **Appbar** layout. I read it was similar to **Linearlayout**.